# For loop: my for loop is not executing properly

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm having trouble getting a for loop in my program to wrok. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been working on it for about 3 hours and still have no clue what to do.

I fixed the while statement. That is not the problem. The problem is with the for loop towards the bottom of the code.

Here is my code:

```
    while(!(strSelection=("5")))
    {
        strSelection=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                                    null, "~~Please make a selection from the menu below~~"+
                                                    "\n\n1. Add a new advisee"+
                                                    "\n2. Update and advisee's information"+
                                                    "\n3. Display all advisees"+
                                                    "\n4. Display advisees who are cleared to graduate"+
                                                    "\n5. Exit"+
                                                    "\n\nWhat is your selection?", "Menu", 3);

        switch(strSelection)
        {
            case "1":

                String strString;
                String strHours;
                int iHours;
                String strMajor;
                boolean blnMajor;
                String strIntent;
                boolean blnIntent;

                adv[iCount]=new Advisee();
                adv[iCount].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is the advisee's name?","Name",3));
                adv[iCount].setID(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is the advisee's ID?","ID",3));
                adv[iCount].setConcentration(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is the advisee's concentration?","Concentration",3));
                adv[iCount].setAdvisor(strAdvisor);
                strHours=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What are the advisee's completed hours?","Completed Hours",3);
                iHours=Integer.parseInt(strHours);
                adv[iCount].setHoursCompleted(iHours);
                strMajor=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Does the advisee have the major sheet?","Major Sheet",3);
                blnMajor=Boolean.parseBoolean(strMajor);
                adv[iCount].setMajorSheet(blnMajor);
                strIntent=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Does the advisee have the intent to graduate form filed?","Intent To Graduate",3);
                blnIntent=Boolean.parseBoolean(strIntent);
                adv[iCount].setIntentFiled(blnIntent);
                iCount++;
                iAccum++;
                break;

            case "2":
                String strUpdateSelection;
                String strOutput="";
                String strAccumulator="";
                System.out.print(iAccum);
                for(iCount=0;iCount==iAccum;iCount++)
                {
                    strOutput=adv[iCount].getName();
                    strAccumulator+=strOutput;
                }

                strUpdateSelection=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                                                null,"~~Please select which advisee's information you need to update~~"+
                                                                "\n"+strOutput+
                                                                "\nWhat is your selection?","Information Update",3);

                break;
            case "5":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }

    }                                           
}
}
```

Comment: A tip would be to only post the code that is giving errors intead of everything. And be concrete about your error :)

Comment: I need it to go through the loop and display all of the advisee's the user inputs.

Comment: This is for a project that is due tomorrow at 9 am. I've been up all night doing it. I didn't knew where else to turn but this site.

Comment: I looked at that link and I don't understand how it pertains to my problem.

Comment: @Treyeyeeyeeye To put it plainly, `while (strSelection != "5")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
while(strSelection!="5")
```

To

```
while(!"5".equals(strSelection))
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart In most cases you won't call "==" operator to compare Strings, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!strSelection.equals("5"))
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing not-equality of a `String`. The way you should do is following

```
 while(!"5".equals(strSelection))
```

Or

```
 while(!strSelection.equals("5"))
```

Not

```
 while(strSelection!="5")
```

And change your `for` loop

```
 for(iCount=0;iCount<=iAccum;iCount++)
```

instead of

```
 for(iCount=0;iCount==iAccum;iCount++)
```

Comment: i understand. I fixed that problem in my code. The problem that i'm having now is with the for loop.

Comment: @Treyeyeeyeeye correct your `for` loop as my answer

Comment: I made that change and now it is giving me a null pointer exception error upon compiling.

Comment: @Treyeyeeyeeye you should figure out what is that issue. There is no way to have null pointer in compile time. Null pointer will throw in run time

Comment: sorry. correction. it was in run time.

Comment: I'm not sure why i'm getting it. I've looked up what a null pointer exception error means. i'm just not sure how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: @Treyeyeeyeeye try with `debug`. Then you will realize.

Comment: "try with debug" ? What does that mean. I've never heard of that. I know i probably sound stupid right now but...

Comment: @Treyeyeeyeeye are you using IDE(Ecplise, NEtbeans, Intellij IDEA) for coding. you should. Then you can use debug feature.

Comment: I'm using notepad++. My class requires me to use that program.

Comment: @Treyeyeeyeeye it is just a text editor. You can't use such a basic editor to do coding. you should use a IDE

Comment: I have eclipse. How would i use the debugger>

Comment: @Treyeyeeyeeye just follow some stuff in google related to coding in Eclips